# How much oxygen does it take to burn a log of wood?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, physical-chemistry, combustion

How much oxygen does it take to burn a log of wood? This is kind of a complex question because the wood itself contains oxygen, so it is not as simple to just compute how much carbon is in the wood and turn it into carbon dioxide. Or maybe it is that simple? I don't know.

For purposes of the question assume the log is white oak and is 7" in diameter and 24" long.

Comment: Yes, complicated.  The wood also has chains of carbon and hydrogen and I would expect some of the hydrogen reacts with atmospheric oxygen to form water + energy, too.  So it seems like you have C-H chains --> water + CO2 + ???  I include the ??? because you also have a lot of "soot" leftover, which must be carbon structures like graphite and such.

Comment: This sounds more like a chemistry question than a physics one.

Comment: There's little in the way of _elemental_ oxygen in the wood.

Answer (score 2):

[Wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood) consists of 70% cellulose and and 30% lignin.
[Cellulose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulose) has the chemical composition $(C_6H_{10}O_5)_n$.
And [lignin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lignin) has the chemical composition $(C_{11}H_{14}O_4)_n$,
which is not very different from the composition of cellulose.
So, let's neglect the difference between lignin and cellulose,
and for simplicity just assume wood is 100% cellulose.

Burning the wood with oxygen produces carbon dioxide
and water. So we get the chemical reaction and the involved masses
(using the molar masses $m_C=12$ g, $m_H=1$ g, $m_O=16$ g)

$$\underbrace{(C_6H_{10}O_5)_n}_{n\cdot 162 \ \text{g}} 
+ \underbrace{6n\ O_2}_{n\cdot 192 \ \text{g}} 
\rightarrow \underbrace{6n\ CO_2}_{n\cdot 264\ \text{g}}
+ \underbrace{5n\ H_2O}_{n\cdot 90\ \text{g}}$$

We see, for burning $162$ g of wood we need
$192$ g of oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/documnts/pdf1984/pette84a.pdf suggests that the elemental composition of wood is 50% C, 6% H, 44% O.  This will be a weight percentage.

Dividing by the elemental mass, we get an atomic ratio of 4.1C:6H:2.4O.

Consuming 4.1 moles of $C$ via complete combustion to $CO_2$ would take double or 8.2 moles of $O$.  Likewise the 6 moles of $H$ takes half or 3 moles of $O$  for combustion to water.  That means almost 9 moles of $O$ over that already present.

Multiplying by the atomic mass means that full combustion of 100g of wood requires something like an additional 160g of oxygen.

Table below ignores the $CO_2$ and $H_2O$ products and only focuses on the oxygen requirements.

| element | mass | moles | moles post combustion | mass post combustion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | 50g | 4.1 | 0 |  |
| H | 6g | 6 | 0 |  |
| O | 44g | 2.44 | -8.89 | -160g |